# Large size dlls with a 'd' suffix

Tags: qt, dll, qml, qt5

I am trying to make stand alone applications for windows platform. I searched for the dlls which my application depended on, placed them with the exe and things worked fine.

Recently, in one of my app, I saw that the dependency being asked are a little different :

1. Qt5Guid.dll instead of Qt5Gui.dll
2. Qt5Declaratived.dll instead of Qt5Declarative.dll

and some more similar kinds..

Common thing is, all these new dependencies are the same old dependencies with a **d** appended to it. When I used the new ones with a 'd', my application worked fine. Problem is all these dlls with 'd' are almost 100Mb more in size than their normal counterparts.

eg:

Qt5Guid.dll  ~ 119 Mb

Qt5Gui.dll   ~ 4 Mb

This is making my package to large in size to give as an application.

Q1. What is the difference between the normal dlls and the counterparts with a **d** suffix. ?

Q2. Can I do something to make my application depend on the normal one explicitly and thus have smaller size of my application ?

Comment: They are almost certainly debug versions of dlls that can be used during debugging. Which one you need will depend on which lib (debug or release) that you link with. [This page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html) has some useful guidance for Qt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt DLLs with `d` suffix are just debug versions. They are needed if an application build in debug mode with `CONFIG+=debug` `make` parameter.

To make an app use the release DLLs, which are significantly smaller, just rebuild your application in release mode.